# Firebase Particular data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new with firebase and was trying to show data according to the email id to recycler view but recycler view is showing the row of it. This is my onCreate method.

```
 mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_project_status");
    //mDatabase.child(email);
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    projects_token=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.selected_projects);

    projects_token.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    projects_token.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter,StatusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter, StatusViewHolder>(Status_getter.class,R.layout.status_row,StatusViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(StatusViewHolder viewHolder, Status_getter model, int position) {
            final String post_key=getRef(position).getKey();
            if(model.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                viewHolder.setProject_name(model.getProject_name());
                viewHolder.setToken_no(model.getToken_no());

            }

            viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i=new Intent(Status.this,Selected_Status.class);
                    i.putExtra("status_id",post_key);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

    };


    projects_token.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

And this is my status_getter class through which I am setting my data. It is called with name model

```
 String token_no,email,progress_dialog,progress_message,project_name,project_description,software_type;

    public String getToken_no() {
        return token_no;
    }


    public String getProject_name() {
        return project_name;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

I have create a xml row namely "Status_row" which makes a custom Recyclerview.

Value stored in my database is like this.
If I add datasnapshot I should have a data key value. Kindly add some sample code with answer because I am just a beginner in this 
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYcV1.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `mDatabase` only instead of `mDatabase.equalTo("email",email)` as the 4th argument of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` anonymous class constructor.

OR

If you want to fetch the data under `email` node, then you can pass `mDatabase.child("email")` as the 4th argument of your `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` anonymous class constructor.

EG:

```
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter,StatusViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Status_getter, StatusViewHolder>(Status_getter.class,R.layout.status_row,StatusViewHolder.class,mDatabase.child("email")) {
...
```